# A comment from Michael Chabon reveals that Romulan marriages are threesomes; has this ever been mentioned before?

Tags: star-trek, romulan

[Some Notes on Romulans](https://michaelchabon.medium.com/some-notes-on-romulans-b1c7f30a383f)

> The term for the Romulan wedding ceremony roughly translates as “A Terror and a Name,” a profoundly secretive ceremony (no guests are invited), in which each of the three (yes) partners reveals their inmost name and deepest fear to the other two. Romulan “marriages” (the word translates as “trust bond”) are always threesomes (in any conﬁguration of genders) because at every moment each partner in the marriage serves as Veriﬁcator to the other two (in Romulan the verb “to verify” is related to verbs meaning. “to police” and “to monitor”), verifying the trust bond of the two others, who are known by a Romulan word that literally translates as “conspirators.” In practice the threesome may or may not cohabit/reproduce — there is great variability here.

I am not sure, but as far as I know only two Romulan families been mentioned, the wife and daughter of Admiral Alidar Jarok and the wife and daughter of Telek R’mor. There has never been suggested that there would be another boundmate.

Has anyone heard anything about that?

Comment: Can you share said Michael Chabon quote? Is it one from https://michaelchabon.medium.com/some-notes-on-romulans-b1c7f30a383f?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes I believe it is

Comment: I wonder if this idea was inspired by Roman triumvirates (especially the political alliances like Caesar + Crassus + Pompey). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triumvirate#Rome

Comment: *has this ever been mentioned before?* No, because they were exhausted.

Comment: The "The Way of D'Era: The Romulan Star Empire" RPG supplement might be worth looking into if one counts that as canonical. It apparently included commentary on political marriages and adultery in Romulan society.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, this suggestion by him has not appeared in a canonical episode. It  might even be contradicted by Season 2 Episode 1 of *Picard*, "[The Star Gazer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Star_Gazer_(episode))", where Romulan housekeeper Laris states that she was promised to her husband at birth, and states that as the Romulan custom, which doesn't seem to match Chabon's statement that three parties come into agreement, although it could be that Laris is telling a falsehood about Romulan culture, or is discussing a sexual relationship rather than a marriage (as Chabon notes that his idea of Romulan marriage doesn't have to do with sex).

Comment: Or perhaps different Romulans have different cultures. I know, it doesn't seem as if the writers have thought of this idea, but it would make sense.

Comment: @Adamant: {nods} Could be it's a "Mandalorian" kind of situation where Laris was an outlier. However, as noted in the question, and from the only reference I've found to how Romulans get married other than Chabon's article, it looks like they operate much like humans and Vulcans, marriages are either monogamous, or at least the Romulans outwardly appear as such.

Comment: @Adamant  while maybe 2000 years is a lot of time - is that enough time for a space colony to really differentiate and also be a singular empire.

Comment: @Adamant yes, that makes a lot of sense. On our own planet we have some cultures that practice polygamy, open marriages, etc. It's possible that some Romulan subgroups do this while others expect monogamy. It's kind of like how not all Klingons have ridges, and ridges can be widely different among different Houses. It represents real diversity, something typically lacking in SF alien cultures.